# Need to allow users to select color from sqllite database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, colors

I need to have colors stored in an sqllite database and have users select the color they want for fonts.
The colors will be displayed in a scrollview similar to displaying icon selections. 
How can I display the colors to the users in this way?

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginRight="73dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="73dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnCreateAccount"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnCreateAccount">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50sp"
                android:layout_height="50sp"
                android:src="@mipmap/color1"
                android:id="@+id/imgView1"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/color2"
                android:id="@+id/imgView2"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/color3"
                android:id="@+id/imgView3"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@mipmap/color4"
                android:id="@+id/imgView4"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

I would think the color would be displayed as an image or icon and the selection will be added to the users file in the database?

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you're asking.  The code you posted seems to be a completely different approach than what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to store the color in the database that is convertable to an android color.

You would have to use

```
Color.parseColor(String colorString);
```

...where the string in the database has the format

```
#RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray'
```

Get the color string from the database, use Color.parseColor(...) to retrieve it as a color, and set the color of the imageview to the returned color.